# SSIS in SQL Agent - "Directory not specified in connection manager"

Tags: ssis, ftp, etl, sql-agent

I have built a package that downloads one or more files from an FTP site to a local directory, deletes all from the FTP, then imports the files into SQL, timestamps the files, then moves it to an archive directory.

Because there can be one or more files I used variables for both source and destination, and put the various tasks in FOR EACH loops.

In BIDS it works fine, but when I run this from SQL Agent, it fails saying

> FTP Task Directory is not specified in the file connection manager

**Control Flow**

[image]

**Error screenshot**

[image]

Why would it run successfully in BIDS but not when scheduled as an SSIS job?

Comment: Make sure that `Delay Validation` property is set to `True` on the components that are using the variables example: `OData Source`, `OLEDB Source`, `FTP Task` ...

Comment: Thanks Hadi, I tried that now but it doesn't work

Comment: You need to provide more details about the package. How the variable value are retrieved and then assigned to the FTP Task?? also providing some screenshot will be better.

Comment: Hi Hadi. The directory it is complaining about is from a file connection manager. It has the appropriate directory. The filenames are then populated in a variable by the FOR EACH loop. I have a stupid question - How do I upload a screenshot here?  Just to add, the part that seems to be failing is after the FTP Task, which uses no variable

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106053/how-do-i-display-image-in-a-post-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Can you show us the configuration of the `Harvest_Assesments` connection manager, and also of any variables associated with it?

Comment: I have found the problem. Thanks digital.aaron. I had a local path in one connection manager